# Selecting only top result from two table query

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Here are my two tables:
Songs:

```
+--------+---------------------+
| SongID |    SongDeviceID     |
+--------+---------------------+
|   3278 | 1079287588763212246 |
|   3279 | 1079287588763212221 |
|   3280 | 1079287588763212230 |
+--------+---------------------+
```

Votes:

```
+--------+--------+
| SongID | UserID |
+--------+--------+
|   3278 |     71 |
|   3278 |     72 |
|   3279 |     71 |
+--------+--------+
```

I am trying to count the number of entries in the `votes` table (for each unique `SongID` and return the `SongDeviceID` of the entry with the most.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Songs.SongDeviceID, COUNT(*) FROM Votes INNER JOIN Songs ON Votes.SongID = Songs.SongId GROUP BY Votes.SongID, Songs.SongDeviceID ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Which returns:

```
+---------------------+----------+
|    SongDeviceID     | Count(*) |
+---------------------+----------+
| 1079287588763212246 |        2 |
| 1079287588763212221 |        1 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

**UPDATE:**
The query has been updated to take care of getting the SongDeviceID but I still need help returning only the first row.

Comment: cant you use order count(*) desc limit by 1

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by 1' at line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   SELECT Songs.SongDeviceID, COUNT(*) FROM Votes INNER JOIN Songs ON Votes.
    SongID =  Songs.SongId GROUP BY Votes.SongID, Songs.SongDeviceID ORDER BY count(*) 
    DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

for first

```
SELECT  SongID,COUNT(*) from votes GROUP BY SongID order by count(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

and you want song device name then

```
SELECT SongID,COUNT(*),SongDeviceID
from
  votes 
left join 
   Songs on votes.songid = song.songid
GROUP BY
   SongID 
order by 
   count(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1
    S.SongDeviceID, COUNT(distinct V.UserID) as 'UserVotes'
from
   Songs as S
join 
  Votes as V on V.SongID = S.SongID
group by
   S.SongDeviceID
order by
  UserVotes DESC
```

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 S.SongDeviceID ,COUNT(distinct V.UserID) as 'UserVotes' from Songs as S join V' at line 1`

Comment: sorry, now it would be okay